# Android studio - Kotlin: How to know if a string is TRULY empty

Tags: android, string, kotlin, is-empty

By TRULY empty, I mean no ways to cheat it. there are many websites on the internet offering empty characters in order to cheat the system and send an empty message. I want to block every single way that this could happen.
MY QUESTION IS: Is there any function in android studio that prevents such things from happening? a function which checks both if the string is empty and if it doesn't contain any empty characters?? or do I have to do it manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isBlank](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-blank.html) to test for the most common whitespace characters (or emptiness), but you'll have to check the exotic ones manually I'm afraid.

Comment: you got any in mind? It actually did prevent all that I knew of so I will upvote this, and once you answer me I'll also mark it as the answer

Comment: I never looked into this stuff so I don't know any in particular that wouldn't be "caught" by isBlank. But I'm sure there must some lists of non white-space characters that are nonetheless invisible.

Comment: There is this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936374/is-there-an-invisible-character-that-is-not-regarded-as-whitespace. The answers mention the BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK (U+2800) character as well as the 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)